# Jquery show hide single link menu-unable to hide on mouse out

Tags: jquery

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".link").click(function(){
            $(".myList").show();
            $(".link1").click(function(){
                $(".myList").hide();
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="myDiv"> <a href="#." class="link">Text</a>
<div class="mylist" style="display:none;"> <a href="#." class="link1">Text</a> <a href="#." class="link1">Text</a> <a href="#."class="link1">Text</a> </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to hide list panel on mouse out, currently I am able to hide it on clicking on any link but want it on mouse out too...

Comment: i think you should add attr or css instead of hide()

Answer (score 2):

Just change the click event to mouseout ;-).

```
$(".link1").mouseout(function(){
    $(".myList").hide()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".link").click(function(ev){ 
    $(".myList").show();
    ev.preventDefault();
});
$(".link1").mouseout(function(){
    $(".myList").hide();
});
```

you had a typo too: mylist & myList

---

try this.

```
$(".link").click(function(ev){ 
    $(".myList").show();
    ev.preventDefault();
});
$(".myList").mouseleave(function(){
    $(".myList").hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks Andy, It is working but still not perfectly.even if my mouse is in myList div it is hiding panel. it should only hide when I move my mouse out of that div.

Answer (score 0):

try using this instead http://jsfiddle.net/G28aH/3/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('.myList').mouseout(function() { $(this).hide(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use animation I think that it's better to use CSS :hover pseudo-class for this task. But if you want to use jQuery then use mouseout event. But in order to prevent dropdown from disappearing when moving over it you should bind event on .myDiv.

```
$('.myDiv').mouseout(function(){
    $(".myList").hide()
})
```

Also you can try hoverIntent plugin which was perfect for my needs. It delays showing and hiding in order to prevent accidental dissapearing.

http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html